# URI formats for linking to a specific app and publisher page on Yandex Store

Tags: android, yandex

I will publish Android games to Yandex. Each game has free version and paid version. In the free version, I have a link to the paid version. In both versions I want to link to **all** my apps on Yandex.

**Question 1. What should be the URI of the link to a specific app?**

For example, on Google Play I use:

```
market://details?id=<package name>
```

... and on Amazon I use:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=<package name>
```

These links are then opened with the following code, for example for Google Play:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package name>");
startActivity(i)
```

**Question 2: What should be the URI of a link to all apps by a certain publisher?**

I want to link a "More Games" button to my publisher page on Yandex (if such a page exists).

On Google play I use:

```
market://search?q=pub:<publisher name>
```

Comment: Yandex.Store supports all types of Google Play intent URLs, susch as:
http://play.google.com/apps/details?id=PACKAGE.NAME
market://details?id=PACKAGE.NAME

Also Store has its own type of intent:
yastore://details?id=PACKAGE.NAME

Comment: and better to surround yastore intent in try-catch, cuz it'll crash if no yandex app on device

Answer (score 0):

// Allows user to Rate this current Application

```
rateme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rateme);
    rateme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                       Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.ENTERPACKAGENAME.ENTERAPPLICATIONNAME") ) );
        }
    });
```